# c++ comparing a reference string to a string

Tags: c++

I have a method that has a parameter which is a reference to a string, in the method I want to compare this referenced string to a another string, this string is part of an object called transaction, there is an array of transactions. Both the original strings are std::strings, I have tried using the == operator but this does not seem to return true even when both strings are the same. Maybe its comparing the address of the strings.

Here is was I have now:

```
int Analyser::numSharesBoughtOf(string& stockSymbol)
{
    // Your code
    int Total=0;

    for (int tranNum(0); tranNum<numOfTranactions; tranNum++)
    {

        if (stockSymbol == Transactions[tranNum].stockSymbol)
        {
            Total = Total + Transactions[tranNum].numShares;
        }
    }

    if (Total > 0)
    {
        return Total;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Transactions is also a pointer to the start of an array of transactions, encase this makes any difference. 
edit:
Thanks for all you replies, turns out that i was entering the wrong name in to the stock symbol... this method does work as does using the .compare answer posted by john.pavan. don't know how i did not notice this before as i was using visual studios debug console, guess its a good thing that i'm not actually in charge of writing code for a stock broker yet haha

Comment: It will simply be true if both strings have the same content. Print the strings you're comparing and the length of each.

Comment: That should work, as std::string has the operator== overloaded.

Comment: Please give the full code.

Comment: On top of the length, you should check for the case as well. Make sure both strings are stripped of whitespaces too.

Comment: Give yourself a wee bit of sanity and dump values of `Transactions[tranNum].stockSymbol` to stderr. (`cerr`). They might not be what you think they are.

Comment: yep you are right that it should have worked. it was an error when entering the stock value, thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use std::string::compare.  Be aware that it works like strcmp, 0 means they're equal.

```
...
if (stockSymbol.compare(Transactions[tranNum].stockSymbol) == 0) {
...
```

Based on the comments, that isn't going to help you.  The only other thing I can think of is that you're comparing strings of different case.  So, convert both to lower, then compare.

```
std::string copy1(stockSymbol);
std::string copy2(Transactions[tranNum].stockSymbol));
std::transform(copy1.begin(), copy1.end(), copy1.begin(), ::tolower);
std::transform(copy2.begin(), copy2.end(), copy1.begin(), ::tolower);
if (copy1 == copy2) {
...
```

Comment: That doesn't offer anything over `operator==` here. If the latter didn't work, the former isn't going to.

Comment: Nevermind, found it in non-member relational operators.

Comment: On that site, it's under [relational operators](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/basic_string/operators/).

Comment: @john.pavan It is a free operator. It (and a dozen or so other such operators) [can be found here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/basic_string/operators/) and/or [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_cmp)

Comment: @john.pavan: Please don't use that site for reference. Prefer http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_cmp

Comment: Gonna update for modifying for case.  Only other thing I could think of.

Comment: This works thanks. turns out that both work and it was an error when entering the string to search for, sorry. would it be more efficient to use you method or just stick with the == operator?

Comment: @RobbieTorrens, They're both the same complexity. I can't think of a case where `compare()` is more readable, to be honest.

Comment: Not the case for standard lib, but some abstraction layers have some modifiers on compare for options like case.